# Invoking rest request from client using webtarget. But paramter of rest resource not getting mapped to client model class parameter

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am invoking rest request via JAX-RS client using Jersey 2.0

```
User request = new User("1","ABC");

webTarget = client.target(strRestURL).path("Users");

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML); 
Response setUserResponse = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(request, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)); 
String resp = setUserResponse.readEntity(String.class);
```

The model class at client side is as follows:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
public class User   {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id;
    private String Name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id= id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name= name;
    }
}
```

Rest WS implementation is :

```
@POST
@Path("/User")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public HSServiceResponse setUsers(final User model, @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
```

Resource User server side :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class User   {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement
    private String id;
    @XmlElement
    private String Name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id= id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name= name;
    }
}
```

Here, `Name` attribute of resource class in server side is recieving value as `null` on recieveing the post request.  However the `id` parameter is getting correctly mapped.

**If I change the param `Name` to `name` in resource class server side implementation. It will work perfectly. However my requirement is to keep rest parameter as Name only("N" capital) and not name("n" small).**

How can I achieve to send request from Jersey client to map `Name` along with `id`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`name`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#name()) attribute of the `@XmlElement` annotation.

```
class UserServer {
    @XmlElement(name="Name")
    private String name;
}
```

This lets you change the XML element name without having to resort to funky variable names in your Java code.

#### UPDATE

For the `User` on the client side, the name of XML element is obtained by the Java bean property, which is the `getName`, removing the `get` and lowercasing the first letter. This is just how JavaBean convention works. If you want to change this, then you should add the `@XmlElement(name="Name")` on the `getName()` method

```
class UserClient {
    @XmlElement(name="Name")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: still did not map from the Rest client . Below xml request from postman works good .It was working before also from postman. But I need to invoke from rest client mentioned above
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<request>
   <id>192183025007</id> 
   <Name>ABC</Name> 
</request>

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood the question. I will update my answer,.